# How to solve diophantine equation $\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}=n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}=n$$ whit $p$ a prime greater than or equal to $3$,for what value to $n$, it's solvable and how to solve,and whether $\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}=q_1$
$\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}=q_2$ is solvable,$\frac{x^p-y^p}{x-y}=q_1q_2$ is solvable too.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's solvable". You read it somewhere? Or it's homework?

Comment: For your last question, wsc, I would think checking an example or two would enable you to answer it yourself.

Comment: Aren't you really asking for "divisibility" instead of "equality"?